# jQuery Replace img issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code (part of the code, but still) loaded via a modal popup:

```
 $("#build").bind("submit", function() {
  $.ajax({
   padding : 15,
   type    : "POST",
   cache   : false,
   url     : "mapStructureDisplay.php?t=build",
   data    : $(this).serializeArray(),
   success: function(data) {
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
    $("#container img[data-coords='<?=$_GET['x']?>, <?=$_GET['y']?>']", window.parent.document).html(data);
   }
  });
  return false;
 });
```

This is what I have at the URL:

```
if($_GET['t'] == "build"){
echo '<img style='background-image:url(images/5.jpg) background-size:60px;' class='xyz' data-alt-src='images/X.png' data-player=' &nbsp; ' data-coords='1880, 2000' src="images/5.jpg" />';
die();}
```

Once the modal popup is loaded the img selector via jQuery is rendered (for example as): `$("#container img[data-coords='1903, 2019']", window.parent.document).html(data);`

The fancybox closes, which is good...problem is the img is not replaced.

The image

```
<img style='background-image:url(images/tile_5.png) background-size:60px;' 
     class='xyz' 
     data-alt-src='images/X.png' 
     data-player=' &nbsp; ' 
     data-coords='1880, 2000' src="images/tile_5.png" 
/>
```

should be replaced with

```
<img style='background-image:url(images/5.jpg) background-size:60px;' 
     class='xyz' 
     data-alt-src='images/X.png' 
     data-player=' &nbsp; ' 
     data-coords='1880, 2000' 
     src="images/5.jpg" 
 />
```

(from the above).

What am I doing wrong?

I have a vague idea that it has to do with me calling the image directly and not the div, but I don't want to refresh the entire div, just replace the image itself.

Comment: check the console and see if the eror is not found

Comment: The console shows no errors, and says that a request was made to page.php?t=build and that the response of it was that of the img element. But it doesn't actually get replaced in the dom.

Comment: just in case, try switching " for ' and backwards. Something there looks like could be the source of the problem. specially in the attribute selector [data-coords='<?=$_GET['x']?>

Comment: Replaced as `$('#container img[data-coords="<?=$_GET['x']?>, <?=$_GET['y']?>"]', window.parent.document).html(data);` ... same result.

Comment: You have a typo in the PHP segment - **echo '<img style='background-image:url** - you have a closing ' just before background. Change to **echo '<img style=\'background-image:url** (escape slash) or **echo '<img style="background-image:url** (quotes)

Comment: I've been trying some other things over the past half hour, one being to change the image replacement to something very simple: `echo '<img src="images/1.jpg" />';` and that doesn't help. I'm at a loss.